# annotation replacement with system properties in weblogic

Tags: java, jboss, jms, weblogic

I am working on a java project, which should listen to the queue destination specified when deployed in application server.

The requirement here is I should externalize the queue properties used in annotation with system properties.

I am using `@MessageDriven` annoation in my class which implements MessageListener and also configuring `@ActivationConfigProperty` with jms queue destination and destination type.

Sample:

```
@MessageDriven( mappedName = "${my_queuename}",activationConfig
= {
    @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destination", propertyValue = "${my_queuedestination}"),            
    @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destinationType", propertyValue = "${my_queuedestinationType}"),
 })
```

I am using system properties substitution in annotation which replaces properties with values configured in system properties. This is working for me in JBoss and I followed steps like:

1. `/subsystem=ee:write-attribute(name=annotation-property-replacement,value=true)`
2. `/system-property=PROPERTY_NAME:add(value=PROPERTY_VALUE)`

Please guide me how to configure system properties in weblogic and enable properties substitution in weblogic.

I am new to weblogic.

I have added system properties in Servers -> Configuration ->Server Start -> Arguments section with java -D .

Sample:

```
java -Dmy_queuedestination=queuedestination
```

I tested queuename, destinationtype, destination propeties without using system property substitution and it is working and able to listen to the queue, but only property substitution is not working.

Any help here is appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Let's format your code snippets.